# Incompatible types - found double[] but expected double

Tags: java

I am currently experiencing a problem with this code:

```
public static double calculategravity(double[] mass, int[] diameter)
  {

      double[] gravity = new double[mass.length];


      for(int n = 0; n < mass.length; n++)
      {
           gravity[n] = (6.67E-11 * mass[n]) / Math.pow((diameter[n] / 2), 2);

      }

      return gravity;

  }
```

Whenever I try to compile it, the following error appears:

```
Incompatible types - found double[] but expected double
```

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `calculategravity` is `double` but you are returning a double array.

Based on the parameters of that method, it makes sense to return an array :

```
public static double[] calculategravity(double[] mass, int[] diameter)
```

Comment: so how should I return a double array?

Comment: @YifeiYan You are already returning a double array. You just have to change the return type of the method, as I have shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Your function return type is `double`, but you are trying to return `gravity` which is array of doubles

Comment: so how should I return a double array?

Comment: see the other answers

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong return type.
You are returning **double** instead of **double[]**.

Try this:

```
public static double[] calculategravity(double[] mass, int[] diameter) {

  double[] gravity = new double[mass.length];


  for(int n = 0; n < mass.length; n++)
  {
       gravity[n] = (6.67E-11 * mass[n]) / Math.pow((diameter[n] / 2), 2);

  }

  return gravity;
}
```